# Error: Syntax error. Extra ','

Tags: formula, formula-field

Update on 4.21.23

I combined the statements you re-wrote @DerekF, added parentheses to close the IF statements (not sure if I did that correctly, I’m still trying to understand the syntax for nested formulas).

I also change the OR statement at the end to add TEXT because they are in a picklist.

I have the edited formula below.

Issue: I tested it in the UI and while there’s no errors when I “Check Syntax”, when I go to test it, the only record types that are correctly populating the right numbers are AHC and BCMH, all the other scenarios result in returning the value 14.87.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

--

I wrote a formula a field in the Case object. I'm trying to do a bunch of nested IF statements that depending on the record type and for some both a record type and a value in another field, it should populate a specific number. I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm getting the "Error: Syntax error. Extra ','"

Here’s what I’m trying to have it return so it populates a formula field with a specific value based upon the criteria.

If the RecordType is “FS” and the Flight_Sch_Formula__c field is populated with “High View” then this field should show 14.87.

If the RecordType is “FS” and the Flight_Sch_Formula__c field is populated with “Low View” and Auth_Start_Date__c is greater or equal to 1/5/20 then it should show 26.52 and if not than 20.52.

If the Record Type is “AHC” then it should show 31.66 If the Record Type is “BCMH” then it should show 42.66.

If the Record Type is not “RC”, “AHC”, “BCMH”, and the Service code is either “202-BA” or “201-Tri” then it should return 644.85.

If the Record Type is “RC” it should return 84.87 unless the value in the field Flight_Sch_Formula__c is "Fair", "Ocean", "Beach", "Sky" which if it is, then the rate should be 92.66.

```
IF(
    RecordType.Name = "FS" && (Flight_Sch_Formula__c), 
    "High View"
), 
14.87,
IF(
    RecordType.Name = "FS" && (Flight_Sch_Formula__c, "Low View") && Auth_Start_Date__c >= DATE(2020, 1, 5), 
    26.52,
    IF(
        RecordType.Name = "AHC", 
        31.66,
        IF(
            RecordType.Name = "BCMH", 
            42.66,
            IF(
                NOT(ISPICKVAL(RecordType.Name, "RC", "AHC", "BCMH")) && 
         ISPICKVAL(Service_Code__c, "202-BA", "201-TRI"),
                644.85,
                IF(
                    RecordType.Name = "RC" && NOT(ISPICKVAL(Flight_Sch_Formula__c, "Fair", "Ocean", 
         "Beach", "Sky")),
                    84.87,
                    92.66
                )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

---

edited formula

```
IF(
    (RecordType.Name = "FS",
    IF(
        Flight_Sch_Formula__c = "High View",
        14.87,
        IF(
            AND(Flight_Sch_Formula__c = "Low View", 
            Auth_Start_Date__c >= DATE(2020, 1, 5)),
            26.52,
            20.52
        )
    ),
    IF(
        RecordType.Name = "AHC", 
        31.66,
        IF(
            RecordType.Name = "BCMH", 
            42.66,
            IF(
                RecordType.Name = "RC",
                CASE(
                    Flight_Sch_Formula__c,
                    "Fair", 92.66,
                    "Ocean", 92.66,
                    "Beach", 92.66, 
                    "Sky", 92.66,
                    84.87
                ),
                IF(
                    OR(TEXT(Service_Code__c) = '202-BA', (TEXT(Service_Code__c) = '201-TRI'), 
                    644.85,
                    0
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: The first step in debugging formulas should almost always be to format it according to best practice (i.e. much like if it were code. One "statement" per line, indent an extra level when you encounter an open paren). It's just too easy for us lowly humans to gloss over things otherwise. I've done this formatting for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues here.

- The `(Flight_Sch_Formula__c), "High View"` and `(Flight_Sch_Formula__c, "Low View")` parts don't make sense. Are you trying to check to see if this other formula field results in those particular values?
- Your first `IF()` appears to be terminated early (there is no "else" part to it)
- You cannot compare multiple values at once, so `ISPICKVAL(RecordType.Name, "RC", "AHC", "BCMH")`, `ISPICKVAL(Service_Code__c, "202-BA", "201-TRI")`, and `ISPICKVAL(Flight_Sch_Formula__c, "Fair", "Ocean", "Beach", "Sky")` are all very incorrect
- `ISPICKVAL()` is used for picklists, neither `RecordType.Name` nor `Flight_Sch_Formula__c` are picklists

As is, there's just too much that's wrong with your formula and not enough information (at time of writing) to suggest how to fix it completely.

About the most help I can offer right now is the following:

- If you structure your `IF()`s with a single condition like you're doing with the "AHC" and "BCMH" record type names, then you don't need to check those again when you get into the "else" portion. I.e. `NOT(ISPICKVAL(RecordType.Name, "RC", "AHC", "BCMH"))` should be able to simply be `RecordType.Name != "RC"`
- If you need to compare a single field against multiple possible values, you should be looking at using the `CASE()` function

+edit: Now we have enough information to get somewhere

Building on the theme that I mentioned earlier (if you have `IF()`s with single conditions, you don't need to check them in the "else" parts), it'll be helpful to do a little extra work in the first `IF()` so you can save yourself some trouble later.

```java
IF(
    RecordType.Name = "FS",
    IF(
        Flight_Sch_Formula__c = "High View",
        14.87,
        IF(
            AND(Flight_Sch_Formula__c = "Low View", Auth_Start_Date__c >= DATE(2020, 1, 5)),
            26.52,
            20.52
        )
    ),
    /* We'll work on the rest of the formula later */
)
```

`&&` and `AND()` accomplish the same thing. I prefer `AND()` because it can be slightly less typing, and I think it's easier to read (especially once you start mixing "and", "or", and "not"). Whichever one you like is fine, just be consistent with it (don't mix-n-match `AND()` and `OR` with `&&` and `||`)

The next part of your formula is fine

```java
    IF(
        RecordType.Name = "AHC", 
        31.66,
        IF(
            RecordType.Name = "BCMH", 
            42.66,
            /* If we get here, we know for a fact that the recordtype is not*/
            /*   FS, AHC, or BCMH thanks to how we've structured the */
            /* IF()s so far */
```

next up, I would suggest that you handle the `RC` case (because once again, we'll be guaranteed that the record type isn't RC, FS, AHC, or BCMH later on)

```java
           IF(
               RecordType.Name = "RC",
               /* CASE() is a more compact way to do an if-else */
               /* Generally much preferred over something like */
               /* OR(Flight_Sch_Formula__c = "Fair", Flight_Sch_Formula__c = "Ocean", etc...) */
               CASE(
                   Flight_Sch_Formula__c,
                   "Fair", 92.66,
                   "Ocean", 92.66,
                   "Beach", 92.66, 
                   "Sky", 92.66,
                   /* Default value if none of the other values are matched */
                   84.87
              ),
```

Using `CASE()` is nice here, because in formulas you can only compare a field to one value at a time. It allows you to avoid typing `Flight_Sch_Formula__c` multiple times.

This sets you up nicely for the final part, checking if `Service_Code__c` is one of those two values

```java
              IF(
                  /* No need to check the record type here */
                  /* It's guaranteed not to be FS, RC, AHC, or BCMH */
                  OR(Service_Code__c = '202-BA', Service_Code__c = '201-TRI'),
                  644.85,
                  /* you must have all 3 parts for the IF() function */
                  /* so you need to determine what decimal to return */
                  0
              )
```

After that, you just need to close up the other `IF()`, which the indentation should make abundantly clear how many you need (if you put the close parens at the same level of indentation as the open parens). I.e. if you have 2 close parens at the same indentation level, or if you don't get back to no indentation, then you've done something wrong.

Comment: @DUser You should edit your question to add that information.

Comment: Just edited, sorry still trying to figure out the best practice on posting

Comment: @DUser No worries, and now that we have enough information about what the fields are and what your intent is, I can give more concrete help.

Comment: Thanks this is super helpful! @DerekF I'm running into a few more issues when I'm testing it in the UI, I edited the post above if you have a chance to look.

Comment: @DUser I've edited your additions. Aside from some whitespace (typical formatting is +4 spaces in each additional indentation level), the main issue is the extra `(` in `(RecordType.Name = "FS",`. Parenthesis must be "balanced" (for each `(`, you need a `)`). Since we can't see your screen, you need to be very precise and detailed about the issues that you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

The first bit of your formula has:

```
IF(
    RecordType.Name = "FS" && (Flight_Sch_Formula__c), 
    "High View"
)
```

The `IF` function needs to be of the format `IF(condition, value_when_true, value_when_false)`. That extra close bracket shouldn't be there.

Check all your `IF` functions to make sure they follow that format.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_if.htm&type=5